# Swift: String.fromCString() didn't work sometimes

Tags: swift, macos

Environment: Xcode 7.2.1 , Swift 2.1.1, OS X 10.11.3.

First I create an osx project (Cocoa Application) using Xcode;

Then I add a simple c++ file like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

extern "C"{
const char* test() {
    //std::string abc = "abc";
    //std::string abc = "abcdeabcde";
    //std::string abc = "abcdeabcdeabcde";
    std::string abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy";

    return abc.data();
}
}
```

And, I call `test()` method at my `AppDelegate.swift` through `CStringTest-Bridging-Header.h`:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    let origin = test()
    let convertResult = String.fromCString(origin)
    print(convertResult!)
}
```

The result of 4 string value in cpp file is shown below:

1. **success**, result is: abc
2. **error**, result is: abciݿ
3. **error**, the `convertResult` is nil, and the console will tell you "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
4. **sometimes success**, print the super long string just like it defined, and the other print nothing

I search on Google and StackOverFlow all the day, and find anything about this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C++ function `test()` has undefined behavior. You cannot use it to produce a valid C string, because variable `std::string abc`, on which you call `data()`, is *local* to the `test()` function.

That is why the value returned from `test()` becomes invalid the moment it gets returned: the destructor is called on the variable `abc`, releasing its data and making the return an invalid "dangling" pointer.

For test purposes you could make `abc` static, and call `c_str()` instead of `data()`:

```
static std::string abc = "...";
return abc.c_str();
```

This will fix the problem, because function-static objects do not get destroyed upon return from the function.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for your answer.